# How can multiple files be committed to git repository with c4droid?

Tags: android, git

I'm trying to get familiar with c4droid at the moment. So far I didn't manage to find any dedicated forum, tutorial or manual for this android app, so it's a hard way of getting the hang of it.

I've set up c4droid so that I'm successfully able to commit single files to my git repository. I do this by a long press on the tab header displaying the file name in the editor component until a dialog is shown which asks for a commit description. However using this approach I have to commit each files separately which I don't want, because 1. it's not convenient and 2. it destroys the internal relationship of an actual commit.

Does anyone know how multiple files can be committed from c4droid with a single commit only?

Comment: If this isn't a proper question which causes some down votes, I would be thankful for a short hint why this is the case so I can consider this for future questions. Thanks!

Comment: Don't get it either. You also got a close vote for being off-topic and it should be moved to Superuser. Completely unjustified imho. This is clearly software development related software.

Comment: There are a couple of questions regarding user handling of e.g. Eclipse around, so I did consider this a valid question - even if the two IDEs do have a different amount of users. But as long as nobody explains the down votes, it's only guessing about their reasons for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some feedback from the developer. He is aware of this issue, but c4droid does not support to commit multiple files in one commit in the moment and there is no plan to change this yet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the С4droid command line and my port git-2.0, which you can find here   https://github.com/fann95/C4droid-Shell